# React TypeScript: How to call an api and set state each time the route changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

useEffect fires perfectly each time I change the route, When I call the API from within useEffect, and then try to set state with the result I get the error `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

I have tried invoking `getPrice` with a self-invoking function and nothing changes, I still get the same error.

Should I be using `Suspense` ??

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Calc: React.FC = () => {

  interface StateInterface {
    priceUsd: number;
  }

  const [price, setPrice] = useState<StateInterface>({
    priceUsd: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPrice = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9999/price', {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          jwtToken: localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'),
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
      });
      if (response.status !== 400) {
        const content = await response.json();
        const priceUsd = content.price[0].priceUsd;
        setPrice({ priceUsd });
      }
    };
    getPrice();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Calc</div>
  )
}
export { Calc };
```

This calc component gets loaded in the router like this

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { globalContext, setGlobalContext } from './components/shell/context';
import { Layout } from './components/shell/layout';
import { defaultState, globalReducer } from './components/shell/reducer';
import { Calc } from './routes/calc';
import { NotFound } from './routes/not-found';

export function Router(): JSX.Element {
  const [global, setGlobal] = useReducer(globalReducer, defaultState);

  return (
    <setGlobalContext.Provider value={{ setGlobal }}>
      <globalContext.Provider value={{ global }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route
            render={({ location }) => (
              <Layout location={location}>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Calc} />
                  <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
              </Layout>
            )}
          />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </globalContext.Provider>
    </setGlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see you return any react element from the functional component, is that the issue?

Comment: I missed it out of the example by mistake, I've added it now

Comment: I can't tell any obvious problem from the code you share. But the error says that, when `setPrice({ priceUsd })` is called, the `<Calc />` component is already unmounted. So the problem is elsewhere, its parent component un-renders the `<Calc />` before completion of `fetch` logic.

Comment: Calc is loaded as a route, nothing special going on in the parent

Comment: Still no sign. Try get rid of `<Layout />` to see if problem goes away.

Comment: Yes the problem goes away if I remove Layout, but I need layout, what is it in Layout that's causing the issue?

Comment: Obviously `Layout` unmount then re-mount its `props.children` somehow.

Comment: I cant thak you enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell any obvious problem from the code you share. But the error says that, when `setPrice({ priceUsd })` is called, the `<Calc />` component is already unmounted.

So the problem is elsewhere, its parent component un-renders the `<Calc />` before completion of fetch logic.

I propose a method to verify, see (+/-) sign for diff:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Calc: React.FC = () => {

  interface StateInterface {
    priceUsd: number;
  }

  const [price, setPrice] = useState<StateInterface>({
    priceUsd: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPrice = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9999/price', {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          jwtToken: localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'),
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
      });
      if (response.status !== 400) {
        const content = await response.json();
        const priceUsd = content.price[0].priceUsd;
-       setPrice({ priceUsd });
+       console.log('calling setPrice()', priceUsd);
      }
    };
    getPrice();

+   return () => { console.log('I got cleaned-up') }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Calc</div>
  )
}

export { Calc };
```

If my theory is correct, we expect to see `"I got cleaned-up"` printed in console first before `"calling setPrice()"`

Comment: I first get the `I got cleaned-up` then I get the same error as I detailed above, then I get `calling setPrice()` 2 times? Do I need a try-catch block?

Comment: Then it confirms my theory. The problem is else where. PLUS, I'm pretty sure `<Calc />` element is rendered twice as two different instance of the same type. Most likely this is because its `key` prop changed.

Comment: @Bill to give me more clue, I need to see the code of route thing, that renders `<Calc />`

Comment: Sure ill post it, I also found this https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h

Comment: @Bill That's next thing you need to worry about, it's another problem, not related to the current one you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the thing what you need to do is write the function outside the `useEffect` and call that function, some thing like this.

```
 const getPrice = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9999/price', {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          jwtToken: localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'),
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
      });
      if (response.status !== 400) {
        const content = response.json();
        const priceUsd = content.price[0].priceUsd;
        setPrice({ priceUsd });
      }
    };

useEffect(() => {
    getPrice();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this and I get the exact same error

Comment: you have used the `await` 2 times, i doubt about it, try removing the one, i updated answer

Comment: I can understand why using await more than once is an issue, but if I remove it the new error is 'Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.ts(2339)

Comment: `console.log(response.json())`  ? check if it is an object or json data

Comment: @techguru he's right. `response.json()` returns a promise that needs to be `await`-ed

Comment: @techguru I'd like to also add, `await` multiple times has zero notable side effect (unnecessary operations do happen tho). You can put `await` before anything, even though it only has real effect when put before promise.

Comment: @techguru It's worth putting your time to fully understand how async-await works. It's based on js generator. Here's a brief [explanation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html). Also checkout the source code of [co lib](https://github.com/tj/co/blob/master/index.js) or the [`__awaiter` source code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLbFRACgEoYBvGYAdz2RgAUAndbVEAUwDoG2R0AbAG5sCAcjjp0IogG4YAXyA). These should help you understand what's going on under the hood.